# How to create a large ArrayBuffer for testing?

Tags: javascript, testing, arraybuffer

A "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error occurred when large array was passed in String.fromCharCode.apply. So I am trying to modify the code as follows. How do I create a large ArrayBuffer to test a modified function?

Original code:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}
```

Modified code:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  let str = '';
  new Uint8Array(ab).forEach((data) => {
    str += String.fromCharCode(data);
  });
  return str;
}
```

Test code:

```
let data;
beforeAll(() => {
  data = createLargeArrayBuffer();
});

test('ab2str', () => {
  const str = ab2str(data);
  const result = str2ab(data);
  expect(result).toStictEqual(data);
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

Comment: How can I fill ArrayBuffer with large random data in a fast and efficient way.?